Bolzano Weierstrass -esque proof for $\mathbb{Q}$ dense in $\mathbb{R}$
I came across a question in a problem set to prove that $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$. I recall some of the classical proof with the Archimedean property etc, but the way that I thought to do it intuitively was to show the existence of a convergent sequence in $\mathbb{Q}$ with a limit as an arbitrary $x \in \mathbb{R}$.
I was just curious to see if my proof sketch is correct, and if so, how to formalize it or make it more rigorous. If it's not, what assumption am I making that's falling apart?
Let $x \in \mathbb{R} \: \backslash \: \mathbb{Q}$. Define $a_1 = \lfloor x \rfloor, \; b_1 = \lceil x \rceil$. Then $a_1 < x < b_1$. Then take $c_1 = \frac{a_1 + b_1}{2}$, which implies $a_1 < c_1 < b_1$. Because $>$ is complete on $\mathbb{R}$, we have either $x > c_1$ or $x < c_1$. Suppose the former, then define $a_2 = c_1, \: b_2 = b_1$. If the latter, then take $a_2 = a_1, \: b_2 = c_1$. Proceeding in this manner, we construct two bounded, monotone sequences (And thus two convergent sequences), with $a_n < x < b_n$.
Even without least upper bound property (If that / Bolzano-Weierstrass doens't necessarily exist on $\mathbb{Q}$ (I saw some other posts about this)), it seems to me that convergence should be possible to prove here. I.e., it seems to me that we can find a way to show that $a_n, b_n$ converge to the same thing, and thus $\lim_{n \to \infty} {c_n} = x$.
Because limits are unique, we show that any $x \in \mathbb{R} \: \backslash \: \mathbb{Q}$ has a sequence in $\mathbb{Q}$ that converges to it. Thus, any point $y \in \mathbb{R}$ is either a point of $\mathbb{Q}$ or a limit point of $\mathbb{Q}$.

Looks good! To show the sequence converges you could prove that it is a Cauchy sequence. This works because the distance between terms is halved every time

How would that show that it converges to $x$ specifically though? Don't I have to show that ${a_n}$ and ${b_n}$ converge to the same thing?

That's easy, the distance between a_(n+1) and x is always less than 1/2^n

Ah, yes, because $|b_n - a_n|$ = $\frac{1}{2} |b_{n-1} - a_{n-1}|$, and so $lim_{n \to \infty} |b_n - a_n| = 0$. Thanks!
